# How high code coverage can indirectly measure quality?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage

In many books, the following statement is quoted:

> This analysis (--code coverage) gives a quantitative measure of the
>   coverage, which is an indirect measure of the quality.

The way I see it, even 100% of statement, branch and even conditional coverage cannot guarantee the code is quality - the tests can be incorrect, the logic (in both source code and tests) might be misunderstood and the coverage might be satisfied artificially.
I am not a developer so maybe I am missing something - how can it be seen as a indirect measure of quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poorly written tests will be found out and corrected.

And the majority of decent programmers automatically check the check-ins of junior coders.  I have seen some horrendous check-ins, even after code reviews from more senior coders.

So...You are generally going to have to accept that the people who you are writing code with aren't inept but do have off days.  Since off days are less frequent than on days the code is going to be of a reasonable standard that a high code coverage will test the more salient points.